# Are there different meanings behind digital to analog in digital audio and PWM?

Tags: pwm, dac, waveform

I'm getting into producing sound waves with various controllers and the two ways DACs are referenced is confusing me.

The first kind of DAC conversion would be from PWM. If a an audio signal is built up of extremely fast changing voltages, PWM isn't doing that. It's just pulsating extremely quickly at different rates so that a speaker will effectively output a wave built up of those simulated voltages. Presumably, to get better output quality, you would convert that to an analog voltage for each small step in the wave.

The other kind of DAC I can only differentiate by calling it a "signal" DAC. If I have a wave made of all of these steps in voltage, a DAC might be used to smooth the transitions to a true analog wave without a sampling rate.

It seems to me like a DAC can be used to convert PWM to analog voltages while still being a digital audio output, then a DAC can also be used to convert that digital signal to an analog wave.

If I want to buy a very fast DAC to just convert a PWM signal to true analog voltages with a sampling rate, what would you call that device when not referring to a DAC that changes a digital audio signal to a completely smooth wave. Being a beginner, I just don't know what to google. There's all sorts of answers about DACs and solutions involving op amps, and the term DAC is everywhere. I'd just like some clarification on what the term refers to in audio and if the definition is somehow changing based on the context.

Comment: The way to convert PWM to audio is by using a low pass filter

Comment: You've spend a lot of time explaining what you think DACs or PWM do in respect of audio and it doesn't really make sense. This also means the sentance "If I want to buy a very fast DAC to just convert a PWM signal to true analog voltages with a sampling rate" sounds nonesense to me. So, take a step back, get rid of the guesswork BS and ask a question.

Comment: May I suggest that you attempt to understand how a **delta-sigma modulator** is used to do both D-to-A and A-to-D conversions. One step in the process involves something very akin to PWM.

Comment: @glen_geek Are you seriously recommending this person to understand delta-sigma modulation? "If I have a wave made of all of these steps in voltage, a DAC might be used to smooth the transitions". Not sure if reading about error feedback and noise shaping will make it clearer.

Comment: @pipe - well argued, but I've seen a few decent entry-level explanations. Its just a matter of effort. It also shows elegantly how a 1-bit D-to-A (like PWM) can extend to 24-bits by applying filters, be they digital or analog. But you're right about the feedback - it is a bit intimidating.

Comment: @Andy aka The purpose of my question was to clarify what a DACs do. Beyond converting a digital signal to an analog one, I didn't know that it doesn't make much sense when talking about PWM. That's why I asked. That sentence doesn't make sense because when asking the question, I didn't know that's not what DACs are for and that PWM does not refer to a digital signal. Sorry if I'm to stupid for this website, but I couldn't find the answer to my specific question through google

Comment: @user So, at the end of the day, questions that are shrouded in false assumptions about "reality" tend to get some stick. As your has. Lesson to be learned by all... If you have a question ask it and don't try to justify what you think you might believe because that only clouds the ability of others to help you. You have accepted an answer but I doubt if you understand the ramifications of that answer - that's another mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DAC is mostly refered to as a device that converts a digital signal (a number) into a value discrete voltage signal followed by a zero order hold. A DAC doesn't use PWM. Class D amplifiers use PWM to drive the speakers and do already provide very smooth currents. If you want to smooth these currents further, you can add a two stage lowpass T-Filter right after the amplifiers output.

Answer (score 2):

Converting digital audio signals to analog signals can be done in a number of ways. The methods that achieve the highest signal quality usually involve signals "pulsating extremely quickly".

The waveforms are often generated by either using pulse-density-modulation (PDM) or pulse-width-modulation (PWM). Both signal types contain an almost perfect replica of the desired audio signal along with components at higher frequencies. Using a scope or a spectrum analyzer these components can be seen, on the scope they don't look smooth.

In order to get a smooth audio signal the higher frequency components have to be removed. In many cases the loudspeaker alone would be sufficient because it can't reproduce "non-smoooth" signals very well due its inertia. However, for a few reasons this method can't be used and filtering has to be applied which results in a clean audio signal.

PDM signals are generated by so-called delta-sigma modulaters and the result is a waveform with two or more voltage levels that contains a high quality replica of the analog signal. Delta-sigma D/A-conversion is mainly done in the digital domain with a final step in the analog domain.

PWM signals are often often considered to be digital signals but this is just a common misconception. They are generated by a pulse-width modulator that takes an analog input signal and by comparing it to some carrier waveform a signal with usually two or three voltage levels is generated. It contains a perfect replica of the input signal and components at higher frequencies.

PWM can be used for D/A conversion as well, but for high-quality audio signals this is a non-trivial undertaking. So most often PWM is not used for D/A-conversion but for the amplification of the signal alone (class-D amplifier). The D/A conversion is often left to an delta-sigma modulator. So PDM and PWM are used together.

Comment: Why should PDM be better suited for DA conversion than PWM? Just because of its wavelet like sampling rate adjustment? Saving this data is much more complicated than saving time descrete data with a fixed sampling rate so delta-sigma demodulation is much more complicated.

Comment: @Simon - Digital PWM for 16-bit or more and 44.1ksps? Do the math.

Comment: @Simon PDM requires much lower digital clock rates than PWM for the same analog output resolution.

Comment: @Mario: This would indeed require a 3 GHz counter, I see. To implement a delta-sigma demodulator in software isn't that hard either. Agreed!

Comment: @user96037: What are the disadvantages?

Comment: @Simon - 3 GHz would be OK. But for PWM  a carrier frequency 10 to 20x the signal frequency is needed. So we have 30 to 60GHz, and only 16-bit!

Comment: @Mario: I can't follow your explanation. How does PWM with a microcomputer need a carrier frequency?

Comment: @Simon. A digital PWM mimics an analog PWM, so the same concepts apply. Using a counter and comparators is similar to having an analog carrier waveform and an analog comparator.

Comment: @Mario: With my 3 GHz counter I can output 16 b data with 44.1 kHz. Why should I use a higher sampling rate on the output than on the input?

Comment: @Simon - PWM generates intermodulation products around the carrier frequency. In order to keep them out of the baseband a higher carrier frequency is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46009/discussion-between-simon-and-mario).

Answer (score 1):

When all is said and done, a PWM output properly integrated and of sufficient rate is indistinguishable from a more ordinary DAC style output.  They BOTH produce (in a different way) a step-wise approximation of the original analog audio waveform. You are creating a false dichotomy here.

Some of the most expensive audiophile power amplifiers have used PWM and indeed most of the most modern consumer gadgets use PWM outputs to drive speakers (and headphones/earbuds, etc.)

One of the reasons that PWM is becoming so much more popular is because it is very easy to generate analog (audio) outputs of any arbitrary precision with only digital circuitry which is dirt-cheap to produce.  It used to take special digital/analog chip technology to produce traditional digital-to-analog converter (DAC) circuits. But welcome to the 21st century. We have learned a lot in the last decade or two.